# React js. Как добавить сообщение о удалении?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет, мне нужно добавить алерт на удаление заметки, как я это могу сделать? Спасибо за ответы!
это код заметок

```
'export const Notes = ({notes, onRemove}) => 
<TransitionGroup component={'ul'} className='list-group'>
{notes.map(note => (
<CSSTransition
key={note.id}
classNames={'note'}
timeout={500}
>
<li 
className='list-group-item note'
>
<div>
<strong>{note.title}</strong>
<small>{note.date}</small>
</div>
<button
type='button'
className='btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm'
onClick={() => onRemove(note.id)}
>
&times;
</button>
</li>
</CSSTransition>
))}
</TransitionGroup>
```

'
Это логика вызова алерта

```
'export const Form = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState('') 
const alert = useContext(AlertContext)
const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext)
const submitHandler = event => {
event.preventDefault()
if(value.trim()) {
firebase.addNote(value.trim()).then(() => {
alert.show('Заметка была созданна', 'success')
}).catch(() => { 
alert.show('Что-то пошло не так', 'danger')
})
setValue('')
} else {
alert.show('Введите название заметки')
}
}
return (
<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
<div className='form-group'>
<input 
type='text' 
className='form-control'
placeholder='Введите название заметки'
value={value}
onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
/>
</div>
</form> 
)
}'
```

Comment: код лучше добавлять текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: и тот код, который вы представили не имеет отношения к удалению, это форма создания

Comment: Я понимаю, но похожим способом это сделать нельзя?

Comment: поправьте сначала вопрос, добавьте код, а не картину и код, который отображает существующий список элементов, а не форму создания.

Comment: Так хорошо? Или как

Comment: @Liubomyr нет это ужасно.Добавьте табуляции.